# VB Prevent negative integers

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am just starting my first class on VB, and my teacher hasn't responded to email in 48 hours and my project is due soon. I am hoping you guys can help me solve this. What I am trying to do is get a program to calculate the total of 3 text boxes and display it in a single label. The catch is, the input in the 3 text boxes cannot be a negative number. I am trying to set it so when a negative number is input it displays a message to enter positive numbers only. However every time I run the program it just calculates the text box with a negative number as 0 and completes the rest of the calculations. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim intPackA As Integer
    Dim intPackB As Integer
    Dim intPackC As Integer
    Dim intCalc As Integer
    Try
        If txtPackA.Text Or txtPackB.Text Or txtPackC.Text <= 0 Then
            lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
        End If
        If txtPackA.Text >= 0 Then
            intPackA = txtPackA.Text * 79.2
        Else
            lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
        End If
        If txtPackB.Text >= 0 Then
            intPackB = txtPackB.Text * 119.4
        Else
            lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
        End If

        If intPackC >= 0 Then
            intPackC = txtPackC.Text * 149.5
        Else
            lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
        End If

        intCalc = intPackA + intPackB + intPackC

        lblCalc.Text = "Package A:  " & intPackA.ToString("c") + vbCrLf & "Package B:  " & intPackB.ToString("c") + vbCrLf & "Package C:  " & intPackC.ToString("c") + vbCrLf + vbCrLf & "Grand Total: " & intCalc.ToString("c")
    Catch
        lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
    End Try

End Sub
```

I know some of the else and if statements are redundant, however if you could give me some pointers on an easy way to condense and clean up as well I would appreciate it.

Comment: This is VB.NET, not vb6, so you shouldn't be mixing Strings with numbers... unless your teacher tell you to do so.

Comment: I'm obliged to say that I think you have accepted the wrong answer here. You really _should not_ be comparing strings with numbers like this; it will lead to all kinds of difficulties. Convert your numbers to integers explicitly first, and check their values afterwards, as Edper suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
  If txtPackA.Text Or txtPackB.Text Or txtPackC.Text <= 0 Then
            lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
   End If
```

Use this

```
If txtPackA.Text <= 0 Then
    lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
    txtPackA.Focus()
    Exit Sub
ElseIf txtPackB.Text <= 0 Then
    lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
    txtPackB.Focus()
    Exit Sub
ElseIf txtPackC.Text <= 0 Then
    lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
    txtPackC.Focus()
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed Santosh, we haven't learned the Exit Sub yet, so I was unaware of this.

Answer (score 2):

Convert first your String input from Textbox into Integer (and store it to an Integer variable) using `TryParse` before comparing like:

```
    Dim valueA, valueB, valueC As Integer
    Dim intPackA, intPackB, intPackC, intCalc As Integer

    Int32.TryParse(txtPackA.Text, valueA)
    Int32.TryParse(txtPackB.Text, valueB)
    Int32.TryParse(txtPackC.Text, valueC)

    If valueA <=0 Or valueB <= 0 Or valueC <= 0 Then
        lblCalc.Text = "Please enter positive numeric values"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Do the rest youserlf or else you have no more to learn as a student.

Answer (score 0):

You will need this ........

```
Private Sub TB_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPackA.KeyPress, txtPackB.KeyPress, txtPackC.KeyPress

    Dim sN As String = "0123456789"
    Dim sO As String = Chr(8) & Chr(13) & Chr(1) & Chr(3) & Chr(22)        

    If Not (sN & sO).Contains(e.KeyChar) Then

        e.Handled = True   

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub TB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPackA.TextChanged, txtPackB.TextChanged, txtPackC.TextChanged

     lblCalc.Text = format(val(txtPackA.Text) + val(txtPackB.Text) + val(txtPackC.Text))

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Matzone, not exactly what I am looking for but it definitely gets the job done.